# Only getting 403 error when updating post via Wordpress Rest API

Tags: wordpress, cors, wordpress-rest-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

So this error has me slightly baffled because it only happens when trying to update a post versus a page. The issue lies with CORS because the error I keep getting is

`Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://{mydomain}.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{post_id} with MIME type text/html.`

I'm not sure why this issue only occurs when trying to update a post and not when I'm updating a page. I am using the exact same method (calling the correct instance) but only receiving the cors issue when trying to update any post.

I'm not sure why this is happening but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try to fix your CORS error via .htaccess with something along the lines of this guide https://wpza.net/accelerated-mobile-pages/how-to-fix-amp-cors-header-error-for-wordpress/ ?

Comment: I tried adding that and get the error "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000', but only one is allowed." I followed the 3 steps that article mentioned but it seems to break everything else now.

Comment: Hi Aj, please note that the above article was mainly to point you in the direction of using the htaccess file. Don't acctually use the AMP resources as you'll most likely not need these. Simply, would `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` solve this?

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for helping and I understood I wasn't supposed to use those urls in place and I've tried just using an * but that also produced the same error

Comment: Very strange that you can do pages but not posts. Are you able to share both code-snippets?

Comment: Yea here is a link to the repo - [Github](https://github.com/ajCastiglione/react-wordpress/tree/master/src/pages). It is under src/pages/pagesingle and postsingle